# Marshalling JSON to XML with jsonix gives invalide XML

Tags: node.js, jsonix

I need to send a xml request to an api for my project. But for security reasons, I cannon't code direct xml in my program. So I decided to use jsonix to marshal JSON to xml, and unmarshal the respond of the request. But I have some problemes.

Here is my xml:

```html
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<api>
    <authentication>
        <login>MyLogin</login>
        <password>MyPassword</password>
    </authentication>
    <command>
        <myfunction>
            <name>test</name>
        </myfunction>
     </command>
</api>
```

With this, I have generated the Mappings with the jsonix-schema-compiler module:

```html
var Search_Module_Factory = function () {
 var Search = {
  name: "Search",
  typeInfos: [{
   localName: "Api.Command",
   typeName: null,
   propertyInfos: [{
    name: "myFunction",
    required: true,
    elementName: {
     localPart: "myfunction"
    },
    typeInfo: ".Api.Command.MyFunction"
   }]
  }, {
   localName: "Api.Authentication",
   typeName: null,
   propertyInfos: [{
    name: "login",
    required: true,
    elementName: {
     localPart: "login"
    }
   }, {
    name: "password",
    required: true,
    elementName: {
     localPart: "password"
    }
   }]
  }, {
   localName: "Api.Command.MyFunction",
   typeName: null,
   propertyInfos: [{
    name: "name",
    required: true,
    elementName: {
     localPart: "name"
    }
   }]
  }, {
   localName: "Api",
   typeName: null,
   propertyInfos: [{
    name: "authentication",
    required: true,
    elementName: {
     localPart: "authentication"
    },
    typeInfo: ".Api.Authentication"
   }, {
    name: "command",
    required: true,
    elementName: {
     localPart: "command"
    },
    typeInfo: ".Api.Command"
   }]
  }],
  elementInfos: [{
   typeInfo: ".Api",
   elementName: {
    localPart: "api"
   }
  }]
 };
 return {
  Search: Search
 };
};
if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
 define([], Search_Module_Factory);
}
else {
 var Search_Module = Search_Module_Factory();
 if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) {
  module.exports.Search = Search_Module.Search;
 }
 else {
  var Search = Search_Module.Search;
 }
}
```

In my main code, I am marshalling the xml request like this:

```html
var Search = require("./mappings/Search").Search;
var context = new Jsonix.Context([ Search]);
var marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

var originalJS = {
   "api": {
    "authentication": {
     "login" :"mylogin",
     "password": "mypassword",
    },
    "command":{
     "myfunction":{
      "name": "test"
     }
    },
   }
  };
var marshalledXML = marshaller.marshalString(originalJS);
console.log(marshalledXML);
```

And in the console.log(), instead of showing me something like this, which is the result I want:

```
<api><authentication><login>mylogin</login><password>mypassword</password></authentication><command><myfunction><name>test</name></myfunction></command></api>
```

It's  returning something like this:

```
<api><authentication><login>mylogin</login><password>mypassword</password></authentication><command/></api>
```

The tag command is always empty, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Thank for your help

Comment: Could you please prepare a JSFiddle for this? I'll take a look.

Comment: Try `myFunction` instead of `myfunction` in JSON.